# Ubuntu - force killing a service

Tags: 20.04, ssh, systemd

I've seen a few topics on this before on AskUbuntu and bits and pieces from other forums but no answer actually solved my query. I'm trying to kill a service on my Ubuntu machine via SSH (Terminal), here's the things that I've tried:

- used systemctl kill [servicename]
- used htop to kill the processes

Is there a way to edit the service file (possibly) so it'll kill the service instead of trying to shut it down (if that's the only way around it)?

The service uses uwsgi, using uwsgi.ini, and it runs on 5 processes which is why killing one doesn't kill it in the end.

After trying to kill it using htop or systemctl kill, it seems the processes respawn, or at least that is what I think is happening from my diagnostics. I'm trying to restart the service to apply the changes that I've made to the code, but annoyingly I can't due to ...this. Any help would be much appreciated.

I've also tried adding in
`Restart=always`
and `RemainAfterExit=no` to the service file but that didn't make a difference either.

Here's the service:

```
Description=uWSGI instance to serve live ver. of project
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
Restart=always
RemainAfterExit=no
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/project
Environment="PATH=/root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/envs/project/bin"
ExecStart=/root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/envs/project/bin/uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: No way to tell anything sensible here without knowing the details of the service. Do you need to launch it in the first place? Perhaps just stop it from launching on bootup.

Comment: Hi @vanadium, I’ll edit the post with details of the service. (What the service file looks like)

Comment: @vanadium There we go, service added to post description. Should be able to see the service now.

Comment: I don't know anything about the uwsgi service. According to the [online documentation](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Upstart.html), the daemon can be started with the option `--die-on-term`. This should make it possible to kill the process via SIGTERM.